# Add increment number at the end for every line

Tags: javascript

Currently I wrote a script to add a prefix & suffix to each line but now I don't know how to add an increment number at the end of the prefix. This is the code so far:

```js
var prefix = '<a href=\"<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>';
var suffix = '</a><!--nextpage-->';
var txt = "http://www.domain.com/\nhttp://www.domain.com/\nhttp://www.domain.com/";
var final = prefix + txt.split('\n').join(suffix + '\n' + prefix) + suffix;
alert(final);
```

I want my final output to look like this:

```
<a href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>http://www.domain.com/2</a><!--nextpage-->
<a href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>http://www.domain.com/3</a><!--nextpage-->
<a href="<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>http://www.domain.com/4</a><!--nextpage-->
```

I want the number to increment starting from 2. I don't exactly know how I would add an increment number at the end of the prefix for each line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep it more similar to your original, you can just use `.map` before your `.join` instead of looping

```js
    var c = 2;
    var prefix = '<a href=\"<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>';
    var suffix = '</a><!--nextpage-->';
    var txt = "http://www.domain.com/\nhttp://www.domain.com/\nhttp://www.domain.com/";
    var final = txt.split('\n').map(function(txt){return prefix + txt + c++ + suffix + '\n'; }).join("");
    alert(final);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop:

```
var txt_bits = txt.split("\n");
for ( i in txt_bits ) {
    txt_bits[i] += (parseInt(i) + 2);
}
var final = prefix + txt_bits.join(suffix + '\n' + prefix) + suffix;
```

Comment: there is a typo in your code. `/n` in your first line.

Comment: Seems to be half working but the numbers are increment by 10. Oh and I don't want leading 0. Here's demo https://jsfiddle.net/4sxdLbc9/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can apply those numbers by using 'map' function of arrays like this (just applying map to your current solvation):

```js
var prefix = '<a href=\"<phpcode><?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?></phpcode>';
var suffix = '</a><!--nextpage-->';
var txt = "http://www.domain.com/\nhttp://www.domain.com/\nhttp://www.domain.com/";
var final = prefix + txt.split('\n').map(function(item, i){return item + (i + 2);}).join(suffix + '\n' + prefix) + suffix;
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

### For React Native using useState()  :

```
    let c = 1; 
    const [topTenAirports, settopTenAirports] =
        useState(`Guangzhou, China (CAN) – 43,767,558
      Atlanta, United States (ATL) – 42,918,685
      Chengdu, China (CTU) – 40,741,509
      Dallas/Fort Worth, United States (DFW) – 39,364, 990
      Shenzhen, China (SZX) – 37,916,054
      Beijing, China (PEK) – 34,513,827
      Denver CO, United States (DEN) – 33,741,129
      Kunming, China (KMG) – 32,990,805
      Shanghai, China (SHA) – 31,165,641
      Xi’an, China (XIY) – 31,073,924`);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
    var final = topTenAirports
          .split('\n')
          .map(function (txt) {
            return c++ + '. ' + txt + '\n';
          })
          .join('');
        settopTenAirports(final);
    },[]);
     
return(<>

<Text style={{textAlign: 'justify', fontSize: 14, padding: 8}}>
                {topTenAirports}
              </Text>
</>)
```

[image]